# How to write numpy array into pandas excel file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to write a set of data from numpy arrays into an excel file using pandas.

I tried to change the dimension the numpy array from 3d to 2d by indexing at 0.  I believe that all numpy arrays are initially 3d.  There seems to be something simple that I am missing but I am not really sure how the array needs to be constructed to write into excel.

Here is my sample code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Numpy arrays
x = np.array([[1.0], [0.99], [0.95], [0.90], [0.85], [0.80], [0.75], [0.70], 
                [0.65], [0.60], [0.55], [0.50], [0.45], [0.40]])
y = np.array([[1.20], [1.19], [1.17], [1.15], [1.12], [1.10], [1.08],
                    [1.06], [1.04], [1.02], [1.00], [1.02], [1.05], [1.07]])

file = 'peaking.xlsx'

# Construct dataframe, index [0] to make 2d 
df = pd.DataFrame([x[0], y[0]], columns = ["X", "Y"])
with pd.ExcelWriter(file, index=False) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

And this is the error that I am getting

`ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You specified the wrong axis, this should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": x[:, 0], "Y": y[:, 0]})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the nesting in your arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Numpy arrays
x = np.array([[1.0], [0.99], [0.95], [0.90], [0.85], [0.80], [0.75], [0.70], 
                [0.65], [0.60], [0.55], [0.50], [0.45], [0.40]])

x = [y[0] for y in x]

y = np.array([[1.20], [1.19], [1.17], [1.15], [1.12], [1.10], [1.08],
                    [1.06], [1.04], [1.02], [1.00], [1.02], [1.05], [1.07]])

y = [x[0] for x in y]

file = 'peaking.xlsx'

# Construct dataframe, index [0] to make 2d 
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':x, 'Y':y}, columns = ["X", "Y"])


with pd.ExcelWriter(file, index=False) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```